# Is there a consolidated list of documentation about Chisel?

Tags: chisel

I am new to RISC-V, Rocket-Chip, and Chisel, and have been searching around for tutorials, and documents, to help me learn to write Chisel code.  It seems to be spread out and new bits and pieces trickle in.  I will answer this question with my list, what have you found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Chisel 2 documentation page, including tutorial, manual, and cheat-sheet:
https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/documentation.html

Chisel 3 wiki: https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel3/wiki

Style guide, which helps those new, like me, understand nuances and figure out how to do non-obvious things:
https://github.com/ccelio/chisel-style-guide

This page has a list of repositories, including chisel example code, a skeleton for new projects, tutorials, documentation (see below):
https://github.com/ucb-bar

The Chisel user group:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/chisel-users

=====================================================

Some items extracted from the above ucb-bar page:

A skeleton for "clean" new Chisel projects:
https://github.com/ucb-bar/pwm-chisel-example

Teaching processors (Simple RISC-V processors, as examples to learn Chisel):
https://github.com/ucb-bar/riscv-sodor

wiki for teaching processors:
https://github.com/ucb-bar/riscv-sodor/wiki

Test harnesses for testing Chisel modules -- [edit] warning: early version for Chisel3, which seems limited to non-interactive tests:
https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-testers

Chisel tutorial:
https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-tutorial

Chisel-doc repository, with its own makefile, that builds documentation:
https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-doc

Comment: Well chisel-testers is definitely not obsolete for chisel3, but it's been restructured quite a bit. Please refer to your provided link.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out -- took a look, and it does seem to work for Chisel 3, but doesn't seem to be able to handle interactive tests.  That's where the tester code reacts to what the DUT does and generates a response.  This makes testing things that have a non-trivial protocol cumbersome.  Maybe this will change over time..  For now, we just wrap the DUT and implement the test code inside a C file.

Answer (score 0):

Will update the answer with more link of various docs/tutorials regarding Chisel -

Chisel tutorial PDF file - https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs250/sp17/handouts/chisel-tutorial.pdf